# Regular Expression Validation Control Disable Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a RegularExpressionValidator Control which checks the correct date from Text Box..

I need to check that text box only when the data is inserted. If it is left empty validating control should allow to proceed further. But all time control denies.

And one thing is that when I enter incorrect date to that text box error message appears but when I enter the correct date after entering incorrect date the errormessage is not disappearing.

My code is :

```
<label for="textarea">Birth Date</label><asp:TextBox 
onkeypress="return isQuote(event);"  ID="txtbdate"  
onfocus="showCalendarControl(this);" onfocusout="return 
validdate(document.form1.txtbdate.text);"  CssClass="TextStyle1 uppercase"  
runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender11" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="txtbdate" Mask="99-99-9999" MaskType="None" AutoComplete="true"
AcceptNegative="Left" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"  
ClearTextOnInvalid="True" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"  
ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Date" 

ValidationExpression="^(?:(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|
[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$|^(?:(?:(?:31\/0?[13578]|1[02])|(?:(?:29|30)\/(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])))
\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$|^(?:29\/0?2\/(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468]
[048]|[13579][26]))))$" ControlToValidate="txtbdate" Display="Dynamic" 
 ValidationGroup="Save" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" SetFocusOnError="true" 
  ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Please Help........

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Validators do not fire when disabled. Disable it by default and re enable it before calling `Validate`

Comment: Just for reference you could just use ^([012]\d|30|31)/(0\d|10|11|12)/\d{4}$ for the regex for the birthday if that's what it should be doing.

Comment: I have set Enabled = false in Source file and in .cs file the code is:
if(txtBdate.Text.Substring(0,2) != "__")
{   RegularExpressionValidator1.Enabled = true;    } 
Still not working... @Simon Whitehead

Answer (score 0):

(If this answer is incorrect, please let me know. Although, from your comments I assume this is your issue)

You need to enable your `Validator` after checking a condition; something like this:

```
if (txtBdate.Text.Substring(0, 2) != "   .") { // not sure why you do this?
    RegularExpressionValidator1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Now, you need to validate the page.. you can do this by calling:

```
Page.Validate(); // <--- this

if (Page.IsValid) {
    // etc..
}
else {
    // not valid..
}
```

I'm pretty sure `Page.IsValid` iterates over each `Validator` in your page and checks it for validity anyway, so you may not need to call `Page.Validate()`.

Comment: The condition if (txtBdate.Text.Substring(0, 2) != "__") is checked to decide whether user has inserted any date or not. If one has entered then only I want to check with RegExValidator.

If user does not enter any date the text box will contain (__/__/____)

Comment: Okay.. so did you try what I said above?